# How to test precaching with workbox?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, workbox

How do we know if our website use assets from cache storage?
Once we store assets in cache storage. Does website use those assets forever until we change revisions for the newest assets?

Comment: Your site uses the cached assets. If you change the name of your cache your service worker will recache it the next time in the new one

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Developer Tools of the browser to verify what's happening with the network requests.

- [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)
- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools)
- [Safari](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari-developer/welcome/mac)

The official docs have various topics to aid in debugging and configuring Workbox cache:

- [Common recipes](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/common-recipes)
- [Troubleshoot and Debug](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/troubleshoot-and-debug)

Capture of the devtools console showing what Workbox is doing (when configured in debug mode):

[image: Workbox console debug]

Capture of the devtools network tab:

[image]

Some extra info for the image above:

- A cog (red square) indicates that a ServiceWorker performed a request to the indicated resources (via [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)).
- If the Size column (purple square) doesn't show a size in numbers, it means that the request was served from a cache (be it memory cache, disk cache, application cache...).