# How to test if Workbox precaching is working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker, workbox

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62483066/how-to-test-precaching-with-workbox).

I'm wondering how I can verify in Google Chrome whether the service worker of my progressive web app is serving precached files from the cache instead of the network.

I have a service worker in place which uses following Workbox code to precache some files:

```
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST); // WB_MANIFEST gets replaced with the files during the build process
```

I can verify that those files are cached within Chrome:
[image]

Here you can see the style.css in row #0.

When I reload my website I can see in Chrome's network tab that the Service Worker received a request for style.css
[image]

After clicking on the style.css entry on the network panel I see following information:
[image]

Here I can see the source of Response which says "Service Worker Cache Storage".
**Does this mean the style.css was sent from the cache instead of the network to the browser?**

I'm a bit confused about that because [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62483066/how-to-test-precaching-with-workbox) I can see a console log entry "[workbox]" Precaching is responding to:" which I can't find on my console:
[image]

And on [this website](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/975517) I can see a separate network entry showing (disk cache) in the size column, which I also don't see on my application:
[image]

I don't think this is related to different versions of Google Chrome as I can reproduce the "(disk cache)" entry by using the ([demo](https://rawgit.com/jeffposnick/7547c69a0780f7782423/raw/c64d054efe60fea88b85b601245bd7157ecdc1e8/index.html)) link.

This is my service worker code, which is respondig with "Workbox loaded":
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed it to create offline support for my pwa. So I think the files are loaded from the cache.